# Almost obvious equivalent det relations?!?

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that, for all $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $(A-B)^2=O_n$, we have
$$
\det(AB-BA)=0 \Leftrightarrow \det A=\det B.
$$

Comment: What makes this "almost obvious"?  What are your thoughts here?

Comment: what stands for $O_2$?

Comment: isn't $A,B\in M_n(\Bbb R)$?

Comment: Yes, I think it should be $O_n$

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by *"at the solution I have found that the solutions is obviously"*.  As it stands, the sentence is incomprehensible.

Comment: I also don't understand what your ?!? adds to the post, or why you insist on putting it back

Comment: My mistakes...Now, it is correct. In the problem book, at solutions section, it's said that the solution is immediate and I have no idea why.

Comment: Could you tell us the book in which you found the problem ? Also, note that the exercise would be simpler if we had to prove that under the condition $(B-A)^2 = 0$, then $AB = BA$ is equivalent to $\mathrm{det}A = \mathrm{det}B$.

Answer (score 1):

This is the case $2 \times 2$.

The case $A = B$ being bona fide obvious, assume, without loss of generality, $N = A - B = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Write
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}\\b_{21}&b_{22}\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Then 
$$
A B - B A 
= 
(B + N) B - B (B + N)
=
B^{2} + N B - B^{2} - B N
=\\=
N B - B N = \begin{bmatrix}b_{21}&b_{22}-b_{11}\\0&-b_{21}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So $\det(A B - BA) = - b_{21}^{2}$.

Now
$$
\det(A) = \det\left(\begin{bmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}+1\\b_{21}&b_{22}\end{bmatrix}\right)
= \det(B) - b_{21}.
$$

Comment: The matrices are $n \times n$, apparently.

Comment: There was an $O_{2}$ at some stage, I hadn't noticed the edit. Thanks @Omnomnomnom